# How would one go from Arrivals CDG T2A to Arrivals CDG T2C?

Tags: transit, cdg, airport-terminals

I intend to first get my baggage at T2A , exit into the arrivals area. Then head to T2C arrivals area to meet my girlfriend. How close are they and what is the exact route to get from T2A to T2C? If anybody has had experience with this movement please share. The idea really is to get an Uber from T2C but first I must get there and I’ve never been to CDG before.

Comment: If there is no need to make an *airside* connection, you might want to mention that fact.

Comment: What is an airside connection? I said I want to go from arrivals to arrivals.

Comment: Our slang.  Airside is the virtual "side" of the airport that is in the sterile area, i.e. Where you have already gone through security.  The rest of the world is "landside".  Most requests of how to change terminals involve changing planes, and it is highly desirable to remain airside, so you do not have the delay of having to clear security again.

Comment: I am not changing planes. I just need to move from 2A to 2C arrivals area only to meet my girlfriend and then get Uber from thereon.

Comment: Yes, I see now where you did discuss that, my apologies, I don't know why I thought otherwise...

Answer (score 6):

Accordingo to [the CDG map](https://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/access/paris-charles-de-gaulle/terminals-map), switching between terminal 2A and 2C requires just a short walk:

[image: CDG T2A]
[image: CDG T2C]

The two terminals are adjacent, therefore your transfer will be easy and smooth.

Comment: Cool map but it doesn’t explain the levels that each terminal arrivals area it is in. Seems like it’s just one floor but seems unlikely.

Comment: Those terminals do indeed have departures and arrivals on the same floor.

Comment: @AliGajani IIRC arrivals is ground level, and it will definitely be the same in T2A and T2C since they are basically identical.

Comment: What’s the difference between level or floor or storey and if they’re on the same level or floor or storey why are elevators and escalators required.

Comment: elevator -> parking lot, escalators: just because there is a single floor doesn't mean that this single floor is always at the same altitude...

Answer (score 2):

It’s quite easy:

- turn right when you exit customs (after baggage claim)
- walk until you reach T2C. It should take a few minutes.

Note that terminals 2A and 2C have a single-floor concept with arrivals and departures on the same level, with the interconnect between the two also on the same level.

Comment: Thanks. If level or floor or storey is same why would they have elevator and escalators though. But I got your point.

Comment: There are elevators and escalators to get to the parking garage, to the link between AC and BD, and a few other thinks like this. But the main arrival/departures floor is common.

Comment: @AliGajani also note that there are not elevators or escalators on the path from Arrivals in 2A to Arrivals in 2C. It is really completely flat and the same level from one to the other.